# which verb means "to give someone advantage in a competition"

Tags: verbs

For example, A and B are going to race. How does A tell B that he'll let B start at 10 meters from the starting line ?

Comment: It's called [a handicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping).

Comment: It's called a handicap, yes, but what you would *say* might be less formal 'I'll give you 10m', 'You can have a 10m head start' or 'I'll give you a 10m start'. All sorts of variations

Comment: How about saying, I will give you a 10m advantage? or a 10m headstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saying I'll give you a 10m **advantage** or a 10m **Headstart**?

[**HeadStart :**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20start)

an advantage granted or achieved at the beginning of a race, a chase, or a competition

a favorable or promising beginning